# Why is my http response code not returned in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, httpresponse

I am trying to authenticate a user in my application.
If the user is not authenticated i'm trying to do following code

```
$eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function($e) use ($app) {
    $response = $e->getResponse();
    $response->setStatusCode(401);
    $response->setContent(json_encode(array(
           'message' => 'You are not authorised for this request',
                'name' => 'Status Forbidden'
    )));
    $app->getEventManager()->trigger(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, $e);
            return $response;
    }, PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Why i'm not able to get the http response code `401` as defined in the code above?

The response content is returned as expected.

Comment: Try: $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(401);
then send your response $this->_helper->json($result), where $result is the response and 401 in better for unauthorized.

Comment: this is done in Module.php file I will not be able to get $this->getResponse() directly  and there is no method "setHttpResponseCode() " for getResponse().

Comment: hey @BhavikJoshi can you please say on which zf2 version you are running?

Comment: its 2.3.* i have downloaded before 3 months

Answer (score 0):

Try to send response before return it and trigger event. I think it's possible when call trigger, response code and content are replaced.

```
$response->sendResponse();
```